# If Any Conditional Statement for Vector of NA elements in R

Tags: r, vector, conditional-statements, na

I ran this `if (any())` conditional statement in `R` with desired result as follows:

```
a <- c(1, 4, 6, 3, 2)
b <- 9
d <- 0
if(any(a < b)) d = d + 1
d
# 1
```

I also ran this `if (any())` conditional statement in `R` with desired result as follows:

```
a <- c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 2)
b <- 9
d <- 0
if(any(a < b)) d = d + 1
d
# 1
```

But this `if (any())` conditional statement in `R` runs with `error message` as follows:

```
a <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
b <- 9
d <- 0
if(any(a < b)) d = d + 1
d
# Error in if (any(a < b)) d = d + 1 : 
  # missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

The vector of `NA` is necessitated as I am running a `for loop` and at the first round, the elements of the vector are not present(missing) but will be populated right from the second run.

**What I Want**

I want a way to do it without the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`any` has argument `na.rm` which you can set as `TRUE` to ignore the `NA` values.

```
a <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
b <- 9
d <- 0
if(any(a < b, na.rm = TRUE)) d = d + 1

d
#[1] 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we can have the first expression to check whether `all` elements in `a` are `NA` or not, and in the `else if` part, we specify `a < b`.

```
if (all(is.na(a))) d = d else if (any(a < b)) d = d + 1

# or better formatted
if (all(is.na(a))) {
  d = d
} else if (any(a < b)) {
  d = d + 1
}
```